# Database Nulls not behaving as Nulls

Tags: php

Php results that excluded null database entries have now stopped working. 
I produced the following test code and it delivers nulls in the result. I am baffled and haven't a clue how to solve. Please help a 75 year old and my first time on an internet question site

```
 <body>  
  <?PHP
    include "dbcfg.php";
    $link = mysqli_connect($mysqlserver, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword,        $dbname) or
            die("Error connecting to mysqli server: " . \mysqli_error());
    if (!$link) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $attractquery = "select * from eatingout where town = 'Newcastle'";
    $result = \mysqli_query($link, $attractquery) or die
                    ("Query to get data from table failed: " . \mysqli_error());
    while ($db_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // iterate through all selected 
        /*if($db_row['image'] != null){*/ 
       /*if (!empty($db_row['image']));{*/
       if(isset($db_row['image']));{ 
        echo $db_row['image'] ." ". $db_row['EOID']."<br/>" ;
        }
    }
        ?>
</body>
```

Results from the above include numerous Nulls followed by EOID numbers from any of the three options. What have I done?

Comment: where do you get nulls, there isn't any places where you use a variable so i'm not sure where you are getting those

Comment: Use `if (!is_null($db_row['image])) {` ... and remove the `;` before the `{` in your if statement.

Comment: ...and wouldn't be better to add `AND image IS NOT NULL` in your `WHERE`-statement in the DB-query?

Comment: Why '\' here`\mysqli_query` ?

Comment: @Rishi could be using a Namespace, in which case the backslash denotes that it's a *root* PHP function... though it's not being used consistently, granted.

Answer (score 1):

You can add NULL test in query:
$attractquery = "select * from eatingout where town = 'Newcastle' AND image is NOT NULL";

Comment: This will filter out all rows that have no image. From the OPs code I don't think this is the expected result, he wants to print all rows but only shows pictures where available.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a string conversion problem?

```
while ($db_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        if(isset($db_row['image']) && $db_row['image'] != NULL && strtolower($db_row['image']) != 'null' ){
            echo $db_row['image'] ." ". $db_row['EOID']."<br/>" ;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the `echo` in the original question is actually writing `NULL` on the screen, this is a distinct possibility; PHP's loose typing means that `NULL == ""` so **nothing** should be output.

Comment: Thanks all for your answers. The solution suggeste by bOne and the implementation from F3L1X79 worked so it is clearly a database string problem even though Null defaults are set in PhPmyAdmin. Maybe to do with uploads from access via Bullzip. Now I need to convert all null strings in the dbase to null

Answer (score 0):

Please check that your columns containt a NULL value and not a string that says "NULL". You should enable for column `image` to have NULL value by ticking the checkbox for NULL

Comment: I am amazed at the response. Tried solution if(!is_null) and removed my error semi colons but to no avail. The program proper goes on to query many fields to eliminate nulls so simply adding the image field to the select enquiry is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>  
  <?PHP
    include "dbcfg.php";
    $link = mysqli_connect($mysqlserver, $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword,        $dbname) or
            die("Error connecting to mysqli server: " . mysqli_error());
    if (!$link) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    $attractquery = "select * from eatingout where town = 'Newcastle' and ifnull(image,'')=''";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $attractquery) or die
                    ("Query to get data from table failed: " . mysqli_error());
    while ($db_row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { // iterate through all selected 
        /*if($db_row['image'] != null){*/ 
       /*if (!empty($db_row['image']));{*/
       if(!is_null($db_row['image'])){ 
        echo $db_row['image'] ." ". $db_row['EOID']."<br/>" ;
        }
    }
        ?>
</body>
```

Kindly remove '\' before mysqli_query and mysqli_error.

You should use !is_null($db_row['image']) instead of isset bcoz $db_row['image'] will always be set.

Secondly you can check the null value in query it self, as mentioned in other answer.

third there is a colan after if clause ie

```
if(isset($db_row['image']));{ 
            echo $db_row['image'] ." ". $db_row['EOID']."<br/>" ;
            }
```